# Connection between the thou/you thee/ye forms of you and the confusion between the thorn (þ) and the letter 'y'?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change, typography, thou-thee-thy

There's a lot of good information in the answer to an existing question about [thou/you and thee/ye](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143352/what-happened-first-ye-you-merging-to-you-or-thou-thee-falling-ou-of), and many are familiar with how shops with the affectation of "Ye Olde Shoppe" get that ["Y" from a corruption of the letter þ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_olde). This might be nothing more than a coincidence, but is there any connection between these two phenomena?

It seems unlikely to me, given how far back the forms of thou/you and thee/ye go (pre-printing press), but one way that coincidence might be explained is if the "y" in you and ye used to be pronounced something like the thorn (which would then make me wonder how the thou and thee were pronounced).

So, can anyone shed any light on whether there's a possible connection here, or can anyone definitely demonstrate that this is purely coincidence?

Comment: You're seriously considering the possibility that the now-obsolete spoken distinction between second person singular and plural pronouns came about because of a quirk of orthography? At a time when hardly anyone could read or write!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, I'm explicitly not, although if you're asking I suppose I didn't make that clear enough. I'm asking if that quirk of orthography was possibly aided due to an alternate pronunciation of 'y' that reinforced it. Exactly because there isn't much (if anything) written down about how people pronounced things back then, I'm wondering if this coincidence might be more than just a coincidence.

Comment: Well, that "quirk of orthography" (the fact that *thorn* looked a bit like *Y*) obviously wasn't aided *enough*, since the letter doesn't even exist any more!

Comment: That's the explanation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter); the form was indistinguishable from  *Y*; the article explains why it disappeared. I always thought it was due to revoking of Edict of Nantes, resulting in French Hugonaut typographers swarming Britain. They hadn't seen the thorn, so replaced it with *Y*. [There is a bit more: there were two letters with the two *th* sounds, thorn and edh (still in Icelandic), representing soft and hard versions. The edh was gradually replaced by the thorn in English. Too bad, it would have nice to have two letters rep the two sounds.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm asking if that quirk of orthography was possibly aided due to an alternate pronunciation of 'y' that reinforced it.

No, there was no such alternate pronunciation.

At the time that *thee* was still in heavy use in much of the English-speaking world, it was as different to the ears and eyes of English speakers as *we* and *I* are today in terms of the perceived meaning, and as different as "thought" and "yacht" in terms of phonetics. *Thee* did not merge with *ye* or *thou* with *you*, but rather in most regions people simply stopped saying the singular *thee* and *thou* except perhaps when they came across it in their prayer book. And when they did say it as part of the Lord's Prayer, they were not confused as to how it was pronounced. *Thee* just died a death out of politeness. People were using the polite plural for more and more groups of people, to the point where nobody was left being covered by the more familiar singular. (Notably, when Quaker "plain speech" revived *thee* with a more egalitarian use, the perceived impoliteness led some to beating up said Quakers).

Meanwhile, the spelling had already become *thee* in almost all use, and when printing started in the English language Þ had already largely been abandoned. Caxton did include Þ in his sorts, but made little use of it. By the time English was being printed, *thee* was not spelled with a thorn.

The main exception the lack of the letter Þ in English printing is as part of the scribal Þ<sup>e</sup>, which of course brings us to the other part of your question, but the inclusion of Þ<sup>e</sup> was akin to the inclusion of & and likewise that scribes at the time still used Þ<sup>e</sup> for *the* was pretty much exactly analogous to people using & for *and* today.

That Þ<sup>e</sup> became Y<sup>e</sup> is due only to Þ looking more like Y in the sort of blackletter typefaces used (where the upper part of the bow of the Þ is thinner than the rest) than any other letter. Had the print styles at the time been closer to the sort of serif and sans-serif typefaces we use today it would likely have become P<sup>e</sup> instead, and people would be saying "Pee Oldie shoppie".

Comment: This answer is great and I couldn't agree more. However, you need to add references to improve it, see [answer].

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey just downvote it, because I'm not going to bother digging up a biography of Caxton or go through a sample of his books counting the letter Þ, so unless I was going to cite something stupid like wikipedia, nope.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't want to down-vote because I know not to be factually flawless. Perhaps I can find references and edit them in, or someone else can have a crack.

Comment: As it happens, [Wikipedia's illustrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)#Abbreviations) of thorn and y are not unhelpful. But they are a bit small for quoting here.

Answer (score 1):

No; Thou and You date back to Proto-Indo-European--French even has cognates: tu and vous. They both date back to the roots [*tú2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/t%C3%BAh%E2%82%82) and [*yūs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you#Etymology).

The fact that "you" used to be spelt ȝou, and gu before that, are very conclusive on their own.

Comment: could you provide some links to help us verify your answer? check out [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) and the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) for help with answering.

Comment: Erm.. What's a PIE?

Comment: @NVZ - Generally a very tasty dish, generally consisting of either a sweet or savoury filling inside a pastry case. Either that or it's Proto Indo-European.